# If a program that should encrypt information on exit crashes

Tags: java

Let's say you have a mail client that stores messages, addresses etc. on the hard drive. These messages are inside encrypted files, but when you sign in they are decrypted so you can access the data inside them.

When you log out these files should be encrypted again. This is easily done if one exits the program successfully, but if somebody pulls the power out of the computer or the program crashes, the instructions to encrypt will not be executed.

Is there a solution to this? If you have any language-specific way to overcome this, I'm using Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: don't *store* the decrypted data. If the point is just to be able to *display* the data, then I see no reason for decrypting *to disk* and then re-encrypting on exit. It would be better to leave it encrypted on disk, decrypt in memory (on demand) and then when the process dies, all is well.

You still potentially need to worry about the process's memory being accessed inappropriately while the data is loaded, but that's a much harder attack vector - and if that becomes a problem, you're likely to be in some pain already.

Comment: What if you've got the page file enabled? If you leave it running long enough would it eventually reach the disk by that route?

Comment: @Jeff you'd have to know your way around the pagefile enough to find the data you're looking for. Like Jon said there's still things to worry about, but they're much more sophisticated than the main problem at hand.

Answer (score 4):

If the messages are not extracted / saved to the disk, then you don't have a problem. This is really how it should be handled - all in memory, for just this sort of situation

Comment: +1 for saying that there is no good reason to decrypt to disk.  I'd add that decrypting to disk is a security risk, given that some other program could read the unencrypted disk files while the mail client is running.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to never store an unencrypted file.

Instead of unencrypting to disk and reading that into your app, read the encryped file into your app, and unencrypt it in memory. Then when your power goes out, you lose data like you haven't saved, but that's what you'd expect.